# How to 'remember' removal of entities (IN UI)

Tags: wit.ai

In the wit.ai UI when entering a story the interface constantly identifies and tags a number of entities that I don't want it to.

[Screenshot showing UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwbzB.png)

In the image above you can see two "package_type" entities being registered against the "How do I buy" sentence.  I cant stop this from happening.  Its wrong.
If I remove them manually, it adds them back in anyway.

I've reached out to their support, with no answer and also tweeted them to see if I can get a response.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define correctly the `package_type` entity in Understanding tab. What search strategy to choose. If you know that package_type will always be one of the standard words from some sort of a list = set it only to be *keywords* and add them in the list (all in Understanding tab). That would be very strict and correct recognition of the entity all the time!

If you set `package_type` to be *free-text* and *keywords* - then that entity will be recognized by the existing keyword OR also you trust wit to "guess" it sometimes - things might go fuzzy here.

And if you use "trait" ... just don't:) don't use it for the type of entities which are more or less defined topics. This is used more for "detecting" the notion of the phrase. Positive \ Negative \ Happy \ Sad... It works - but it's a little fuzzy too:)

So just switch `package_type` to keywords, add some package types to the keywords list and see how the recognition works.

Made this: https://wit.ai/yuraantonov/My%20First%20App/entities

Comment: Thanks.  I had it set as keyword, but the "free text" option was also selected.  I think perhaps I have misunerstood the purpose of that particular option.  I'll revisit the docs.  Thanks for your help